# Jarrod's looking a little off kilter these days

Tags: bug, status-completed, tour

iPhone
[image: iphone]

iPad
[image: ipad]

Comment: duh.  he's in morganton.  have you ever been to morganton?  you'd be off-kilter too.

Comment: Is it true that in Scotland, you can be arrested for being an off-kilter?

Comment: @earlz please stop adding ridiculous tags to posts. I'm getting to the point where this is a warning.

Comment: @Jeff... :( ok...... But but. But. Jarrod needs his own.. But. The new meme.. But.. sigh ok.

Comment: I was so tempted to not fix and just mark this `status-bydesign`, but we gots to look professional now!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The camera this photo was taken with (Canon PowerShot A630) detects the orientation of the camera when the photo was taken to automatically rotate it. However rather than physically rotating the jpeg, it sets the [orientation in the exif meta data](http://park2.wakwak.com/~tsuruzoh/Computer/Digicams/exif-e.html#IFD0Tags). Since a lot of programs ignore this flag, someone has then physically rotated the photo to correct it manually, but left behind the exif setting. Obviously whatever the iphone/ipad use to render images reads the exif info, so it applies a second rotation to "correct" the image, meaning it displays sideways.

Comment: Hence the reason that embedding orientation in an image is pure evil. My phone can do this and the pictures will be side ways and I'll turn my phone and it will "correct" the orientation for me and keep it sideways. Pure evil I tell you

Comment: Ya - it's better to just rotate it (the image) in-camera instead of relying on any auto-detection stuff.

Comment: @Earlz - It's great in theory (100% lossless & instant rotations) iff *all* software supported it. But given most software doesn't & half of those that do are built by monkeys like your phone example, I have to concede that yes, in practice it is evil.

Comment: @George - Its not really about the auto-detection, its about the implementation of "rotate". Rotating it as you describe in-camera wouldn't help if your camera did it by changing the exif orientation.

Comment: Very cool observation - I opened the image in Photoshop; sure enough, it was rotated as depicted in the question!  Simple to fix, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Jarrod - it may take some time for you to regain your balance after fixing this. This is normal, as the fluid in your inner ear will need to settle.

Comment: Nice answer, but you left me wondering *why* a browser would take Exif information into account...

Comment: @Arjan: My (completely unverifiable) guess is that its a combination of three things: 1) the iphone has a camera & can detect its orientation, so photos taken by it store orientation information in the exif information. 2) When viewing the image back on the iphone it reads the exif information so it automatically gets displayed the "right way up". 3) The browser uses the same underlying image rendering engine, meaning it also reads the exif information. (then of course the ipad does the same thing even though it doesn't have a camera since its the same code base)

Comment: But still *why*... I guess it's a bug after all: a browser should not do that. Maybe it's even showing the Exif preview itself, so one could specify another image for the iPad. ;-) I also wonder what the iPad will do with specified HTML `width` and `height` attributes then...